# How to populate a pre-existing multi-dimensional array with corresponding $_POST values?

Tags: php, post, recursion, multidimensional-array, overwrite

I can't find a function that does what `array_replace_recursive` does without creating new values from the 2nd array.

Basically I have this array with empty values for constructive purposes. I then wanna copy data from `$_POST` that has the same keys. But I don't want values of foreign keys to be copied.

```
$array = array(
  'one' => '',
  'two' => array(
    'this' => '',
    'that' => '',
  ),
  // ...
);

$_POST = array(
  'one' => 'a',
  'two' => array(
    'this' => 'b',
    'that' => 'c',
    'dontcopyme' => '...',
  ),
  'dontcopyme' => 'x',
  // ...
);

//$new_array = array_merge_recursive($array, $_POST);
//$new_array = array_replace_reursive($array, $_POST);
$new_array = array_dosomemagic($array, $_POST);
```

The result I am after in this demonstrative case:

```
array(
  'one' => 'a'
  'two' => array(
    'this' => 'b'
    'that' => 'c'
  )
)

print_r($new_array);
```

Note: Multidimensional arrays

Comment: Can you provide short but real sample of both arrays(with sample result)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not a sexy one-liner, but recursion is rather difficult to jam into one line.

My method includes some important `isset()` checks along the way to ensure that array elements exist before trying to access them.  You shouldn't see any Warnings/Notices with my function.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b73e8e93329afdb683f2854f6a18c06d92ca53c8))

```
function recursivePopulate($defaults,$post){
    foreach($defaults as $key=>&$elem){  // make $elem modifiable by reference
        if(!is_array($elem) && isset($post[$key])){  // if not an array and matching element in $_POST
            $elem=$post[$key];  // store $post 
        }elseif(isset($post[$key])){  // only recurse subarray if exists in BOTH arrays
            $elem=recursivePopulate($elem,$post[$key]); // recurse using subarray
        }
    }
    return $defaults;
}

$defaults=[
    'one'=>'one',
    'two'=>[
        'this'=>'this',
        'that'=>'that',
            ['deep'=>'no match']
    ]
];

$_POST=[
  'one'=>'New One',
  'two'=>[
    'this'=>'New This',
    'that'=>'New That',
    'dontcopyme'=>'...'
  ],
  'dontcopyme' => 'X'
];

var_export(recursivePopulate($defaults,$_POST));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one' => 'New One',
  'two' => 
  array (
    'this' => 'New This',
    'that' => 'New That',
    0 => 
    array (
      'deep' => 'no match',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want [array_intersect_key()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```
<?php
$array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
$array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));

array(2) {
  ["blue"]=>
  int(1)
  ["green"]=>
  int(3)
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure, but multidimensional?

Comment: You just need to write a simple function based on array_intersect_key that checks if current key is an array or a value